# Any way to make ST_Intersection reliable for geographic data?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

`ST_Intersection` looks not reliable, it sometimes gives wrong results (contradicted to other postgis functions) for corder cases, like linestrings that intersect 180 longitude.

For example:

```
postgres=# select st_asText(ST_Intersection(ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(115 76, 104 50)'),ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(173 66, -175 66)')));
                  st_astext                  
---------------------------------------------
 POINT(109.44160371422937 65.99999999999999)
postgres=# select ST_Intersects(ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(115 76, 104 50)'),ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(173 66, -175 66)'));
 st_intersects 
---------------
 f
```

ST_Intersects return false (there are no intersection), but `ST_Intersection` return not empty set.

What the problem with `linestring` that intersection 180 longitude,
should I do some magic to fix this for all corner cases (north/south poles, 0 and 180 longigtude), or it is impossible with postgis + geography and should use something else?

I use postgis 3.2.0, postgresql 13.4

Comment: It seems to be documented in  http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geography.html (not so well in https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html) "The buffer and intersection functions are actually wrappers on top of a cast to geometry, and are not carried out natively in spherical coordinates. As a result, they may fail to return correct results for objects with very large extents that cannot be cleanly converted to a planar representation." LINESTRING(173 66, -175 66) as geography takes the direct route across the dateline (12 degrees) so st_intersects=false is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @user30184 said, intersection for geography type is just a wrapper that will actually project your data in the best local UTM if possible, and otherwise fallback to 3857 (if I remember correctly). It's easy to use, but can fail like in your case, because in 3857 (which is I think used in your case because there shouldn't be local UTM that crosses this border), when you take the closest line between 2 point, in the plan, you crosses the entire world.

You should first find the best projection for you problem, and use the intersection on projected geom. You can look [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421302/postgis-polygon-crossing-latitude-0-and-longitude-180/421367#421367) at my answer to a similar problem where the polygon crosses both the 180° lng and the north pole.